# webbrowser control anchor tag vb.net winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, browser, anchor

I have a question about the webbroswer control regarding anchor tags.  Is it possible to programmactically in vb.net go to an anchor tag in a webbrowser control?  I would like to ideally provide a combo box drop down on the winform form and control which part of the html page the user goes to when the user makes a selection from the combo box.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should just be able to:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("#someAnchor")
```